# Split URL in javascript at last instance of '&'

Tags: javascript, regex

I saw a bunch of URL splitting techniques on this site but could find one for what i need.

I need the last parameter chopped off.

ie. 
http://www.website.com/Pages/SearchResultsPage.aspx?k=website&cs=This%20Site&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.website.com%2FOur-Commitment

to

http://www.website.com/Pages/SearchResultsPage.aspx?k=website&cs=This%20Site

The URL will not always be the same and so the solution must somehow search for the last "&" and strip it off.

I managed to do this but i was hoping for less lines:

```
rewriteURL();  

function rewriteURL() {
    var url = window.location;
    var urlparts = url.split(/[\s&]+/);
    var newURL = urlparts[0] + '&' + urlparts[1];
    window.location.href = newURL;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to not rely on order of the parameters and actually remove a specific named parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function rewriteURL() {
  window.location.href = window.location.href.substring(0, window.location.href.lastIndexOf('&'));
}
```

Comment: +1, yours is shorter, although IMO you should set the location ;)

Comment: Corrected my answer - thejh pointed out that window.location isn't a string - oops!

Answer (score 3):

```
var loc = window.location + '';
var url = loc.substring(0, loc.lastIndexOf('&'));
```

`window.location` is not a string.

Comment: I find `window.location.href` to be clearer than `window.location + ''`.

Answer (score 1):

```
function rewriteURL() {
    var urlparts = window.location.href.split(/[\s&]+/);
    window.location.href = urlparts[0] + '&' + urlparts[1];
}
```

(Point is, does it matter that much?)

My bigger concern would be that I'd be afraid the parameter order might change, or there'd be additional parameters, etc. Better to do it right and be certain.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @thejh is better, but for a fun one-liner:

```
var newLoc = location.href.split('&').slice(0,-1).join('&');
// "http://www.website.com/Pages/SearchResultsPage.aspx?k=website&cs=This%20Site"
```